# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ has atleast four idempotent elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $m, n > 1$ are positive integers which are relatively prime. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ has atleast four idempotent elements. Two of them are $[0], [1]$, how will I find the other two?

Comment: There are really only two other 'natural' guesses, aren't there?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the equation $x^2 \equiv x$ is true mod $mn$  if and only if it is true mod $m$ and mod $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$x$ is an idemptent element implies $mn$ divides $x(x-1)$ so if $mn$ divides $x$ you have $x=0$ and if $mn$ divides $x-1$ you have $x=1$ what if $n$ divides $x$ and $m$ divides $x-1$ you will find another and if you permte $m$ and $n$ you will find the fourth.

The list of the idemptent elements: $0,1,nu,mv,\cdots$ where $nu+mv=1$

Comment: Should be $\, 1-nu,\ 1-mv,\ $ and there may be more.